# Flutter unscape html string inside a variable

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart

On the server side, I'm using this code to send a text as HTML:

```dart
Route::get('about-us', function () {
    return response()->json(
        '<p>about-us</p>'
    );
});
```

As you can see, this text is not escaped, but when I receive it on the client side with Flutter, it comes like this:

```html
"<p>about-us<\/p>"
```

The problem is that I cannot convert this text to:

```html
"<p>about-us</p>"
```

I tried to use the [html_unescape](https://pub.dev/packages/html_unescape) package, and it works correctly when I use it like this:

```dart
var unescape = HtmlUnescape();
print('===>  ${unescape.convert('<p>about-us<\/p>')}');
```

But when the HTML text is inside a variable, it doesn't work correctly. For example:

```dart
var unescape = HtmlUnescape();
print(data);                               //return: "<p>about-us<\/p>"
print('===>  ${unescape.convert(data!)}'); //return: ===>  "<p>about-us<\/p>"
print('++++>  ${unescape.convert('<p>about-us<\/p>')}'); //return: ++++>  <p>about-us</p>
```